# Watir message: Instead of passing arguments into #wait_until_present method, use keywords

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I use watir with firefox to grab a webpage after filling a form. Here a short part of my code:

```
browser.button(:type => 'submit').click
sleep 10
browser.element(:id => 'footer').wait_until_present(timeout=30)
html = browser.html
```

This message occur:

```
Instead of passing arguments into #wait_until_present method, use Keywords
```

What does that mean? How can i solve this?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is on the new Watir 6.0 FAQ:
http://watir.github.io/watir-6-faq/#G

In your case, change from `timeout=30` to `timeout: 30` and you won't see the warning message.

Answer (score 0):

The API of watir says `#wait_until_present(timeout = nil) ⇒ Object`

The `timeout = nil` part is an optional parameter, if you want a timeout you just need to pass a number to the method.

```
browser.element(:id => 'footer').wait_until_present(30)
```

Comment: The API changed with Watir 6.0 which was released 2 weeks ago.